# Geany snippets: change the outcome of %cursor%

Tags: cursor, code-snippets, geany

I love Geany and I love Geany snippets.
However I found an annoying little quirk: the result of "a=" e.g. `<a href="%cursor%" target="%cursor%" class="%cursor%">` is `<a href="_" target="_" class="_"`. So there's a space added and a "_" in that space. Where is the %cursor% defined in Geany and how can we change it?

Answer (score 1):

it is defined in snippets configuration file. This file is stored on Data folder of Geany install location which is "c:\Program Files\Geany\data\snippets.conf" on Windows.

```
# use %cursor% to define where the cursor should be placed after completion. You can define multiple
#     %cursor% wildcards and use the "Move cursor in snippet" to jump to the next defined cursor
#     position in the completed snippet.
```

However if you want to customize snippet file then you normally edit file of your own user which you can acess in menu:
**Tool - Configuration file - snippets.conf**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Keybindings -> Editor -> Move cursor in snippet` then set your keybinding, for me I use `CTRL+]`. This action quite useful when you use in snippets. It's like when you press the `CTRL+]`, it will jump to the next `_` which is `%cursor%`, and the `_` will be selected(I mean highlighted), then you can just type anything on it without pressing `Backspace`.

And [Geany WebDev Snippets](https://github.com/zhaolinlau/Geany-WebDev-Snippets) is my version of snippets for web development(HTML, JavaScript, PHP, Vue) in Geany, you may use it if you want to. Hope it helps.